# Android: How to display .mht file?

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to display `.mht` file in Android, so I used webview like this:

```
byte[] bytes = tblK.getmhtmlFile();
String s = new String(bytes);
webview.loadData(s,"text/html;charset=utf-8","UTF-8");
```

and, it shows like this:

[image]

How to avoid those unwanted content from webview ?

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Webview is not a perfect one, It does not support mht files directly. I suggest you to try the below options for displaying mht files.

1.[Android Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs)

2.[Chormium Webview Library](https://github.com/mogoweb/chromium_webview)

Comment: Those are the only two options?